# When is type casting SQL columns required?

Tags: mysql, casting, mariadb

I performed the first query and did not get my expected results.  I then realized that `1 slope` was interpreted as an integer, thus `t.slope` in `t.slope*pchp.sign*p.slope slope, t.intercept+t.slope*pchp.sign*p.intercept intercept` was also acting as an integer.

I then repeated the query but this time casting both `slope` and `intercept` as decimals, and obtained the correct results.

I then repeated the query a second time but only time cast `slope` whose value was not zero but not `intercept`, and also obtained the correct results.

Which leads me to my question.  When is type casting SQL columns required?

```
MariaDB [testing]> WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    -> SELECT id, id pointsId, type, 0 value, 0 prevValue, 1 slope, 0 intercept
    -> FROM points
    -> WHERE id IN (406, 428)
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT t.id, pchp.pointsId, p.type, p.value, p.prevValue, t.slope*pchp.sign*p.slope slope, t.intercept+t.slope*pchp.sign*p.intercept intercept
    -> FROM t
    -> INNER JOIN points_custom_has_points pchp ON pchp.pointsCustomId=t.pointsId
    -> INNER JOIN points p ON p.id=pchp.pointsId
    -> )
    -> SELECT id, SUM(slope*value+intercept) value, SUM(slope*prevValue+intercept) prevValue FROM t WHERE type='real' GROUP BY id;
+-----+--------+-----------+
| id  | value  | prevValue |
+-----+--------+-----------+
| 406 |      0 |         0 |
| 428 | 123702 |    123702 |
+-----+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testing]> WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    -> SELECT id, id pointsId, type, 0 value, 0 prevValue, CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) slope, CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) intercept
    -> FROM points
    -> WHERE id IN (406, 428)
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT t.id, pchp.pointsId, p.type, p.value, p.prevValue, t.slope*pchp.sign*p.slope slope, t.intercept+t.slope*pchp.sign*p.intercept intercept
    -> FROM t
    -> INNER JOIN points_custom_has_points pchp ON pchp.pointsCustomId=t.pointsId
    -> INNER JOIN points p ON p.id=pchp.pointsId
    -> )
    -> SELECT id, SUM(slope*value+intercept) value, SUM(slope*prevValue+intercept) prevValue FROM t WHERE type='real' GROUP BY id;
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| id  | value       | prevValue   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 406 |  49480.8000 |  49480.8000 |
| 428 | 123702.0000 | 123702.0000 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testing]> WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    -> SELECT id, id pointsId, type, 0 value, 0 prevValue, CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) slope, 0 intercept
    -> FROM points
    -> WHERE id IN (406, 428)
    -> UNION ALL
    -> SELECT t.id, pchp.pointsId, p.type, p.value, p.prevValue, t.slope*pchp.sign*p.slope slope, t.intercept+t.slope*pchp.sign*p.intercept intercept
    -> FROM t
    -> INNER JOIN points_custom_has_points pchp ON pchp.pointsCustomId=t.pointsId
    -> INNER JOIN points p ON p.id=pchp.pointsId
    -> )
    -> SELECT id, SUM(slope*value+intercept) value, SUM(slope*prevValue+intercept) prevValue FROM t WHERE type='real' GROUP BY id;
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| id  | value       | prevValue   |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| 406 |  49480.8000 |  49480.8000 |
| 428 | 123702.0000 | 123702.0000 |
+-----+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testing]>
```

Table definitions are as follows:

```
MariaDB [testing]> explain points;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idPublic       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| accountsId     | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name           | varchar(45) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value          | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| prevValue      | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| units          | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type           | char(8)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| slope          | float       | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| intercept      | float       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| tsValueUpdated | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sourceTypeId   | tinyint(4)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testing]> explain points_custom_has_points;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pointsCustomId | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| pointsId       | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sign           | tinyint(4) | NO   | MUL | 1       |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [testing]>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some (concise) table definitions.  In general, you should always cast when necessary, and in fact many other databases are much more strict than MySQL/MariaDB in this regard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Definitions were added.  Yes, I assumed I should always do so when necessary :)  But when is it necessary?  Your remark that other databases are more strict leads me to believe I should always do so unless the column data type is dictated by the table definition, and I should also type cast the `0` for integer even though it worked without doing so.

Comment: Humm, Will `sign tinyint(4)` cause issues?

Answer (score 0):

Change `CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) slope` to `1.0 slope`.  If that works, then here is the explanation:

The *first* `SELECT` in a `UNION` determines the datatype of each column.  So, simply saying `1` would set the slope to some flavor of integer (I think `BIGINT`).

You may have similar issues with other columns.

I suspect you cannot swap the `SELECTs` in that `UNION` because of `WITH`.  But that might be another thing to try.  (Please report back if you do try it.)